# Can we override executionTimeout set by client application in it's httprequest in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-10

I have a single Asp.net web application with just one Aspx page and no user interface, as well as a Salesforce application. This web application serves only as a web service for us.
We are using HttpRequest with a 2-minute timeout to call this asp.net endpoint from Salesforce.
This http request times out and fails if it takes longer than two minutes.
I know that we can set executionTimeout in httpruntime in web.config but it will apply for all the requests.
I want to set executionTimeout runtime based on certain information received from http request. Like if incoming http request is big then increase timeout and otherwise don't change it.
I search on google but don't found any solution.
So, I want to know whether it is possible or not and if possible then how to implement it.

Comment: Any HTTP request that requires a long time to process is a red flag. If you cannot ensure an API call finishes within a reasonable amount of time, you should redesign that API to something like a state machine, or use bidirectional channel like SignalR/WebSocket. Don't bother messing up with timeout values, as that only leads you further down the wrong path.

Comment: @LexLi - I totally agree with you that long running process should not be processed like this. In future, we are going to re-design solution to handle long running processes in background in disconnected way from Client. But, for short term solution I am just trying to find some way to increase timeout at runtime, if possible.

Comment: Try to set the server ScriptTimeout:
HttpContext.Current.Server.ScriptTimeout